# Presto SQL pivoting based on a set of yes/no column values

Tags: sql, pivot, presto, trino

I have a table with a list of tasks, each of with helps satisfy one or more legal regulation, and has the status of each task. I would like to group by the Regulation name in my presto SQL table, which is a subset of the column names. Here's the table:

| Task | Regulation1 | Regulation2 | Regulation3 | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task1 | Yes | No | Yes | On Track |
| Task2 | No | No | Yes | On Track |
| Task3 | Yes | No | No | At Risk |
| Task4 | No | No | Yes | Blocked |

I'd like the output to be one row per Regulation pivoted by the status with the count of tasks, like this:
[image]

I don't know how to do a "Group By" based on a subset of the column names so not sure how to do this. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way but the one I came up with is a bit cumbersome - it involves grouping and then using `unnest` on "synthetic" arrays:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(Task, Regulation1, Regulation2, Regulation3, Status) as (
    values ('Task1', 'Yes', 'No',    'Yes', 'On Track'),
        ('Task2', 'No', 'No',    'Yes', 'On Track'),
        ('Task3', 'Yes',    'No',    'No',  'At Risk'),
        ('Task4', 'No', 'No',    'Yes', 'Blocked')
)

-- query
select regulation,
       sum(on_track) on_track,
       sum(at_risk) at_risk,
       sum(blocked) blocked
from(
    select Status,
           count_if(Regulation1 = 'Yes') Regulation1,
           count_if(Regulation2 = 'Yes') Regulation2,
           count_if(Regulation3 = 'Yes') Regulation3
    from dataset
    group by Status),
unnest(array['Regulation1', 'Regulation2', 'Regulation3'],
    array[if(Status='On Track', Regulation1), if(Status='On Track', Regulation2), if(Status='On Track', Regulation3)],
    array[if(Status='At Risk', Regulation1), if(Status='At Risk', Regulation2), if(Status='At Risk', Regulation3)],
    array[if(Status='Blocked', Regulation1), if(Status='Blocked', Regulation2), if(Status='Blocked', Regulation3)]
    ) as t(regulation, on_track, at_risk, blocked)
group by regulation;
```

Output:

| regulation | on_track | at_risk | blocked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Regulation2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Regulation3 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| Regulation1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |